# Any example to upgrade an aws eks cluster using github actions workflow on a self-hosted runner outside of cluster?

Tags: github-actions, amazon-eks, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Are there examples for this use case,
ie to upgrade an aws eks cluster using github actions workflow on a self-hosted runner which is outside of that cluster ?